# Cross-platform interactive ebook in iBooks Author

Tags: ebook-readers, apple-books

I'm attempting to create a choose-your-own-adventure ebook in iBooks Author. However, in formats other than the mac store, the links do not work. I can export it as an epub but the links will only work in iBooks. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where a very user-friendly tool works well on only one platform.

Before I say anything else, you should have learned how to create and edit links in HTML. Also, it might help to use css which allows you to force a new page. Sample code here: http://www.paulsalvette.com/2012/04/adding-page-breaks-for-your-kindle.html (Keep in mind that ebook support for page breaks has improved but is still lacking in Google play books).

Creating hyperlinks in HTML for epub files is extremely simple. Unfortunately ibooks author probably generates a lot of hard-to-edit code (I'm guessing).  If you can unzip the .epub (an epub is just a zip with its suffix renamed to epub), you can probably make those changes manually. But that might be a lot of trouble.

Actually if you're testing the links, you could probably test with Adobe Digital Editions or the Readium in Chrome

I don't know why you choose ibooks author, but you probably would have had more luck with creating your ebook in sigil. You need to test the html files before you make an epub file.

One thing. I am a gigantic fan of CYOA, but here are 2 things you should know:

1. "Choose your own adventure" is trademarked. I would call it a "maze story" which is not trademarked.  I think there are some bona fide CYOA stories as ebooks, but I think the publisher created an app to host those stories. (By the way, looking over the print CYOA is very interesting. you can appreciate the artistic choices. I blogged about the series [here](http://www.imaginaryplanet.net/weblogs/idiotprogrammer/2010/11/november-literary-linkdump-1/) (skip down a bit)).
2. This author Rudolf Kerkhoven has created some interesting (and successful) maze stories in Kindle. Check out "The Adventures of Whatley Tupper"

Comment: If the OP is using any of the more advanced features of ePub with iBooks Author, then they won't be able to fix this with Sigil because iBooks Author uses a modified version of ePub 3.0 and Sigil can only handle ePub 2.0 (it actively breaks ePub 3.0 files).